# User-driven messages missing header

Tags: civimail

I am struggling to find the answer to why my default mailing header / footer are not being attached to user-driven driven message, specifically member renewal notifications. I get the email body just fine and the tokens are working, just not either the header or footer.

CiviCRM 5.20.2 on Wordpress 5.3